# Check sleep settings from command line?

Tags: debian, power-management

How does sleep work on a Linux (Debian) box? I do not usually use the box with a keyboard and mouse. I usually SSH into it. Does it sleep, but then "wake up" when I connect to it?

What if I were running a web server? Would it sleep until a GET request arrived, then wake up, or would it just ignore incoming packets when sleeping?

I have a background process that I do not want suspended. How can I check from the command line what the sleep settings are?

How does the "power management" capability decide when to sleep and when not to sleep? Does it look at the running processes and somehow decide to sleep based on what those processes are?

Answer (score 2):

That's a large topic.  Start with `ACPI` (*Advanced Configuration and Power Interface*).  It has been provided with Linux since the early 2000s.

Very briefly, it's managed via the BIOS, which can be configured to check for activity on the devices attached to the computer, and use that to trigger the CPU wakeup.

- [Understanding Suspend](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnderstandingSuspend) (Ubuntu wiki)
- [ACPI: Advanced Configuration and Power Interface](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/ACPI-HOWTO/) (Linux HOWTO)
- [How Does Power Management Work?](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2919/2)

It's possible to wakeup on network activity (although the typical Debian system probably is not configured for this).  For that related topic see

- [Wake On LAN](https://wiki.debian.org/WakeOnLan) (Debian wiki).
  At the bottom of this page, it lists manual-page links for various tools which *may* be useful to you (as usual, your *specific* configuration is what determines which are useful): 
  [ethtool(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=8&query=ethtool&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en), [etherwake(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=8&query=etherwake&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en), [wakeonlan(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=wakeonlan&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en)
- [HowTo: Wake Up Computers Using Linux Command [ Wake-on-LAN ( WOL ) ]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-send-wake-on-lan-wol-magic-packets.html)

Comment: If the BIOS is only program/software that is active during a suspend and the BIOS itself responds to wakeup signals from hardware devices (laptop lid , power switches etc) then I take it the types of events the OP mentioned, remote incoming SSH connection, or a request to a webserver cannot cause a system to wake up - as these processes are completely suspended.

Comment: That depends on the hardware interfaces for the network.

Comment: This does not answer the basic question which is how to check (and understand) the power management settings from the Debian command line.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't answer any of the questions I asked, one of which was a yes or no question.

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas Dickey said, power management is a quite multi-layered thing. He covered mostly the low-level/hardware interface side, but I take it you're more interested in the higher-level arrangements.

At the very bottom in user perspective, there is the `powermgmt-base` package, which just contains some scripts like `/sbin/acpi_available`, `/sbin/apm_available` and `/usr/bin/on_ac_power`, which can be used to determine the current power state and general ACPI/APM capability in other scripts.

On top of that is usually `upower`, which is the modern interface between user sessions and the power management framework. It communicates over D-Bus. It uses tools and scripts in the `pm-utils` package to actually trigger power management operations like suspend-to-RAM or sleep, and PolicyKit (package `policykit-1`) to decide who and/or what is allowed to give the order for such operations.

On top of `upower`, there is either `gnome-power-manager` (Gnome), `powerdevil` (KDE) or `sleepd` (none of the above/optional) that would actually trigger power management actions as necessary.

The `pm-utils` package can use a lot of tools from various packages, like `hibernate`, `uswsusp`, `ethtool`, `hdparm` and `cpufrequtils` among others to perform its actions. It also has a lot of hooks for customization: those hooks can be used to perform actions at sleep/wakeup, or to stop an unwanted sleep operation.

Typically a web server would not sleep in the power management sense when waiting for clients: it sure would idle with the CPU underclocked while there is nothing to do, though. Waking up from sleep mode takes a bit of time, and that might cause too much of extra latency in the web service. But if you specifically want, it might be possible to have your network card wake your system from sleep mode (or even from a complete shutdown) as traffic is detected: see `ethtool <network interface> | grep Wake-on` for which wake-up features your NIC supports.

`upower --dump` will list any batteries, displays and other relevant things the power management knows about: on my desktop, it even knows about the battery status of my wireless mouse.

If your system does not include `gnome-power-manager`, `powerdevil` or `sleepd`, then I don't think it will go to sleep automatically in any situation (other than laptop/UPS battery being critically low, possibly). These are the components that can decide to put the system to sleep on their own, according to their configured power policy. You should look at the documentation of these components, whichever of them may be applicable to your system.